# Как в bash искать файлы в полной назве каких есть одинаковые цифры

Tags: ubuntu, bash, find

Я создал куча папок типу: "0/0/0"    "0/0/1"  и т.д "9/9/9"  (три уровня в каждом по 10 подкаталогов от 0 до 9) в каждой папке создал файл с назвой 1.txt . Подскажите как мне найти файлы в полной назве которых есть одинаковые цифры ( например 3/5/3/1.txt или 1/3/9/1.txt) и вывести эти названиие на экран

Comment: Похоже на то, что у кого-то лаба по информатике. Тут подобное не любят, но мне тоже интересно как решить подобную задачу.

Comment: Чтобы получить названия, где есть повторяющиеся части на Питоне: `for parts in product(digits, repeat=3):
     if len(set(parts)) < len(parts) or '1' in parts:
           print(Path(*parts) / '1.txt')
`

Comment: Читай `man awk`

Comment: Что-то типа `find /path/to/begin/with -name "1.txt" | while read f; do x=${f%\.txt}; if echo $x | tr '/' '\n'| sort | uniq -c | grep -q '^[[:space:]]\+2 '; then echo $f; fi; done`. Писалось быстро и на коленке, уверен, можно упростить. Если пользоваться регулярными выражениями с метками, то точно find+sed сделают всё. А ну и там надо не **на 2** проверять, а **на не 1** (подробнее в `man grep`).